# Determining the regions of the z-plane for $|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|<1,|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|=1,|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Hello so I am trying to determine the region on the z-plane for
$|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|<1,|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|=1,|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|>1$
when $|\bar{a}|<1,|\bar{a}|=1,|\bar{a}|>1$ (so 9 cases in general).
I have started with $|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|=1$ by
$$|\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}|^2=1^2$$
and from that finding
$$(|z|^2-1)(|a|^2-1)=0$$ Iknow this is supposed to be a circle? Can someone explain to me what this circle looks like and how this is an equation of a circle. From this I know when $|a|=1$ the z region is all z. Can someone point me in the direction of determining the other 8 parts?

Comment: the equation of a circle is $|z-z_0| = r >0$, in your case, $|z| = 1$: a circle centered at the origin with radius $1$.

Comment: @hellofriends but what about a, which is also complex?

Comment: I'm talking about your last case in particular: $|a| \neq 1$ and $(|z|^2-1)(|a|^2-1) =0$

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer ; just an insight)

A certain level of understanding of these so-called Möbius transforms defined by

$$f_a(z)=\frac{z+a}{1+\bar{a}z}$$

is brought by geometrical representations.

[image]

Here is one in the case $a=0.3+0.4i$ (case $|a|<1$). The unit circle is represented by a thick black contour. On the left, a set of circles with common center the origin. On the right, their images by Möbius transform $f_a$ (Colors are preserved). One can see (this isn't a proof, just for convincing yourself) that in this case $|a|<1$ : $f_a$ sends

- the unit *disk* $\mathbb{D}$ onto the unit disk,
- the unit *circle* onto the unit circle and
- the complement of unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ onto itself.

Comment: Any comment ?...